# scope.$watch doesn't fire with hash object (associative array)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a problem with my scope.$watch, I have two components and one controller, in the first component I can check some checkboxes and when I check these I update a variable that contains all the checked objects :

```
scope.values[well].selected = !scope.values[well].selected;
if (!scope.selectedWells.includes(scope.values[well])) {
  scope.selectedWells.push(scope.values[well]);
} else {
  var index = scope.selectedWells.indexOf(scope.values[well]);
  if (index > -1) {
     scope.selectedWells.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

With this code it's working well, when I modify my selectedWells object then in my second component the event is catch :

```
scope.$watch('selectedWells', reloadLegend, true);
```

The problem is that I need to make my selectedWells object an hash object (associative array), to have something that looks like this :

```
{
  'wellNumber1' : {}
}
```

So I edit my code to this :

```
scope.values[well].selected = !scope.values[well].selected;

// Add or remove from the selectedWells
if (!scope.selectedWells[well]) {
  scope.selectedWells[well] = scope.values[well];
} else {
  delete scope.selectedWells[well];
}
```

It works well too in the first component, but my event is not catched anymore.

Why does this work with an "simple" array but not with an associative one ?

**EDIT :**

Here is a second example of my problem :

```
var currentScreen = {};
$scope.$watch('currentScreen', function() {
  console.log("screen changed");
}, false);

/**
 * Get a screen by id
 * @param id
 */
function getDefaultScreen(id) {
  $timeout(function () {
    ScreensService.customShow('get', 'example')
      .then(getScreen)
      .catch(getScreenFailed);

    function getScreen(data) {
      console.log(data);
      currentScreen = data;
    }

    function getScreenFailed(e) {
      ...
      return $q.reject(e);
    }
  });
}
```

The get screen return an object like this : `{A01: {…}, A02: {…}, A03: {…}, A04: {…}, A05: {…}, …}`

But the event is not fired when the `currentScreen` change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a deep watch:

```
$scope.$watch('currentScreen', function() {
  console.log("screen changed");
̶}̶,̶ ̶f̶a̶l̶s̶e̶)̶;̶
}, true);
```

The shallow watch (with `false`) only checks for changes in the object *reference*. The deep watch (with `true`) checks for changes in the *contents*.

[image]

For information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - `$scope` Watch Depths](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-watch-depths).